# Use of "more" with noun

Tags: comparative-constructions

Why doesn't this sentence say "more dangerous"? Why use the *"more of + noun"* construction?" I'm confused here. Do "*More + adjective*" and "*More of + noun"* have the same meaning? Could you give other examples in the structure "*More of + noun*?" I usually just say *"more + adjecti*ve".

> *He attacked with such pace and I believe he was **more of a danger** than Pele at the time - he was a phenomenon, capable of sheer magic*

> *Could = softener, **more of a suggestion**.*

Comment: Does this page answer your question? https://www.thoughtco.com/the-use-of-more-in-english-1210666#:~:text='More'%20is%20placed%20before%20a,are%20more%20students%20this%20year). Note that we don't use "more of + noun", only "more of + determiner + noun".

Comment: @JavaLatte How do you phrase "more of + noun? Does it have the same meaning as "more + adjective?"

Comment: It depends entirely on the specific noun (which may either not even *have* a corresponding derived, or that adjective might carry different semantic connotations and / or syntactic affordances). Consider *We never intended my wife to get pregnant last year, so baby Jane was **more of a mistake** than a planned addition to the family.* In which context *...baby Jane **was more mistaken...*** would be nonsense.

Comment: Personally, I think there's a tendency for ***a danger*** in such contexts to refer to a potential risk that you ***need to deal with / neutralize***, as opposed to something ***dangerous*** that you ***need to run away from / avoid***. But that's just me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So the word "of" means "like" in this context, doesn't it? "**More of a danger**" means "more like a danger". "**More of a suggestion**" means "more like a suggestion. Is my interpretation right?

Comment: I don't know if there's any similar construction in your own language, but it won't necessarily help *you* to say *the word "of" means "like" in this context*. Because I'm an Anglophone, I can say that *in my "mistake" example*, the words "of" and "like" mean the same thing - but what they mean is effectively nothing anyway, since it's perfectly possible to say *Baby Jane was **more a mistake** than a planned addition* with nothing in between ***more*** and ***a mistake***. That's a slightly different construction to *He was more of a danger than Pele*, where "of" is almost mandatory.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I still don't understand. Does ***more of a** mistake* mean *to make more of a mistake* or ***closer to a** mistake*? Which the word "of" means "closer to".

Comment: The "meaning" of *Baby Jane was **more a mistake** than [something else]* is ***It would be more accurate** to refer to Baby Jane as "a mistake" rather than "[something else]"*. It's a ***noun, "label"*** that's being "endorsed". That's as opposed to the *X is more ADJ than Y* format of the Pele example, where the final two words are implicit but rarely included; *He was more dangerous than Pele [**was dangerous**]* (the extent to which he was dangerous was greater than the extent to which Pele was dangerous).

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @FumbleFingers How do you paraphrase "in more of a mood"? Does "more of" mean "more like" here? *She seemed to be **in even more of a mood** for needling me than normal.*

Comment: To *be in [even] more of a mood* is just an emphatic version of [*be in a mood*.](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-in-a-mood), same as *be in more of a pickle /  bind / spot, on more of a roll,* etc. Your example isn't very idiomatic to my ear, because ***in a mood*** is usually an idiom meaning ***angry***, but your use is more literal: *She seemed **even more inclined to needle me** [than normal].*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. To be in more of a pickle / bind / spot, on more of a roll, etc. Are your examples idiomatic and natural here?

Comment: What do you mean by "here"? Look them up!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I meant to say are your examples idiomatic in this context and can be used in everyday speech? *To be in more of a pickle / bind / spot, on more of a roll, etc*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Some nouns can be used gradably in descriptions, rather like adjectives.

She's a great nuisance. (= She's very annoying)
The meeting is a relative success. (= ... relatively succesful). Can I say "more of a nuisance" to mean "more annoying?" Man Utd look a *more of a threat* on the counter. More of a threat = a greather degree of help. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, except you've got an unwanted extra article in *Man Utd look **a** more of a threat...* It should just be *Man Utd look more of a threat..*

Comment: @FumbleFingers How do you paraprhase these sentences? To be in more of a pickle / bind / spot, on more of a roll, etc.

Comment: I probably wouldn't bother trying to shoehorn idiomatic expressions like that into comparative or superlative versions. I'd just say I was even worse off, or still getting lucky.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions ***more** NP* and ***more of** NP* have various paraphrases depending on context, but their meanings are generally similar.

In your first example, “he was more of a danger than Pele at the time,” the phrase *more of a danger* means a greater danger.

Consider a different example, one inspired by the aphorism that “March comes in like a lion and goes out like a lamb,” which means that the weather early in that month is typically harsh but by four weeks later becomes much milder. If one year there were a blizzard on the 24th, one might remark, “Today is **more lion than lamb**,” which refers implicitly to the aphorism and points out the day’s not conforming with the pattern the aphorism expresses.

In *During the emergency, the Governor’s wife was **more of a leader** than he*, the meaning is that she **acted more like** a leader, or **showed more** leader**ship** than he.

If a television critic said, “The show’s cancellation is **more mercy killing** than **murder**,” it would mean that the series was—perhaps had become—so bad that ceasing its production was almost a favor, and certainly was nothing to object to.

Comment: What is confusing me is the word "of" here. What does it mean? Does it mean "more like"? "More of a danger" = more like danger.

Comment: **As always**, much depends on context. In **some** contexts, like your Pete example, ***more of a** danger* can be paraphrased perfectly by ***a greater** danger*. In that example, it is quite different from ***more like a** danger*.

Comment: That makes sense. What about the sentence *Messy is **more of a** striker than a midfilder*. Would you paraphrase ***more of a** striker* as ***a greater** striker*?

Comment: It means that Messy more nearly constitutes the ideal striker than he does the ideal midfielder.

Comment: In this context, does "more of" mean "more about?" *It's **more of a** guess than an estimate*.

Comment: No, this latest sentence means it’s **better described as** a guess **than as** an estimate, which is to say that the term *a guess* **describes it better than** the term *an estimate* **does**.

Comment: Some nouns can be used gradably in descriptions, rather like adjectives. She's a great nuisance. (= She's very annoying) The meeting is a relative success. (= ... relatively succesful). Can I say "more of a nuisance" to mean "more annoying?" Man Utd look a more of a threat on the counter. More of a threat = a greater degree of threat. You've been **more of a** help = You've been a greater help.  Am I right?

Comment: Each of your *more of a nuisance*, *more of a threat* and *more of a help* is fine, **provided** that either you state explicitly or it’s clear from context what the *… **than what**?* is. And usually, instead of *more of a help*, we would say *more helpful*, unless you’re contrasting with something like *a hindrance*.

Comment: Can I say *You're **in more of** trouble*?  / *She seems to be **in more of a** mood*.

Comment: No, \**You’re in more **of** trouble* does not work. As to the second, it depends on context and what you wish to mean, but it doesn’t sound very natural.

Answer (score 0):

**more + adjective** means more of the quality defined by the adjective

> John is more reliable than most taxi drivers

**more + noun** means a larger number or quantity:

> I have more books than he has
> I need more cheese

**more of a + noun** means more of the qualities that define the noun

> Soon after that, a woman, small, slender and almond faced, more of a pixie than a person, sat down next to the union boss. *Heroes of the New Eden, Charles Morgan, 2012*